# Changing background color on a specific day in VIS.JS timeline

Tags: css, timeline, vis.js

I use vis.js timeline, and it works great.

The issue is with the way the CSS class changes when you zoom in and out, as I have it now, every other week changes color ( grey and white ) works perfectly when zoom is set at showing week numbers, but zooming in to days the formation is gone, as week now doesn't exist.

My workaround was to change Monday to Sunday every other time, but I haven't found a way to do that.

The code I think to use in some way is:

/* This changes the color of the selected day ( weekends this time )

```
  .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-saturday,
  .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-sunday {
    background: gray;
  }
```

What I need to figure out and what I can't seem to wrap my head around is, how to get Monday to Sunday, every other time? So I match the further out zoom of weeks.

Any help! How that could be done or if it is actually possible would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue, it may not be the correct way, but it does what I need it to do.

what I did, was making a new Group, ( as I place some new items on the timeline numbering the weeks ( this is optional )

on that group i then added
that code is like this:

```
groups.add([{id: 0}]);

items.add({
id: 'week' + random,
group: week,
content: 'week ' + number,
start: weekstart,
end: weekend,
type: range
className:'Weektophidden', 
});

items.add({
id: 'week' + random,
group: week,
content: 'week ' + number,
start: weekstart,
end: weekend,
type: range
className: alternateweekcolor, 
});
```

the variables are linked to some CSS and math finding out when the week is starting and ending.

if anyone knows a more correct way to solve this, I would still like to know, so I can be wiser on this vis.js program.